# How to extract Friend-List using Facebook-Graph-API V2.9?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

Unable to fetch friend-list using facebook-GraphApi-V2.9.
Request Url is as follows : **graph.get("me/friends")**.

Same Url is working in API V2.4, V2.5 etc.Any way to create a sample application which can use lower API version?

Facebook-Graph-Api-v2.9 :[Output-V2.9 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZIew.png)

Facebook-Graph-Api-v2.5 :[Output-V2.5 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeQaM.png)

Comment: what´s not working? what is the result? any error?

Comment: @luschn No error its returning null in data part.

Comment: do you get a total_count value? did some of your friends authorize that 2.5 app? you do know about the fact that you can only get friends who authorized your app, right?

Comment: Yes check the output with V2.9 Graph-Api :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZIew.png and V2.5 Graph-Api :-https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeQaM.png

Comment: looks good to me. make sure that your friends authorized the app too, with user_friends. this was changed with v2.0 already.

Comment: Okay,You can check with V2.5.its working

Comment: most likely you are using a different app that some of your friends authorized already

Comment: That's fine but this thing specifically not working with V2.9.I am using same app not different

Comment: so ARE there friends of yours who authorized the app with user_friends? if not, then the result of v2.9 would be correct. if yes, then you should file a bug.

Comment: @luschn Yes, I have checked.

Comment: Absolutely no difference between the v5 and the v9 output for me - I see the same friends listed in both cases.

Comment: @cbore you can check  image links.According to you what can be the possible issue for me ?

Comment: @luschn;@cbore I have filed this as a bug and its assigned now (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1195388200589462/) :)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook accepted this is a valid Bug ([Link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1195388200589462/)).